# SUMIFS based on dynamic Sum_Range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to use `SumIFs` formula where i want to use dynamic sum range.

column range is selected from another sheet in same workbook base on a cell value in current sheet

**My Formula:**

```
=SUMIFS ( <XYZ> , CriteriaRange1, Criteria1, CriteriaRange2, Criteria2)
```

I want `<xyz>` to be dynamic column range selection based on a cell value.

Comment: It seems like you'd have to have dynamic criteria ranges as well, or you'll get a #VALUE error if they're not the same number of rows.

Comment: What exactly is the cell value on which the dynamic range should be based and how does that give you the range?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INDIRECT()`

If, say, your formula is in Sheet2 cell A1, it bases itself on a cell B1 in which there is `Sheet1!A:A`, you can use:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(A2), CriteriaRange1, Criteria1, CriteriaRange2, Criteria2)
```

If cell B1 has only `A`, you will have to construct the address from the `INDIRECT()` function:

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&A2&":"&A2), CriteriaRange1, Criteria1, CriteriaRange2, Criteria2)
```

Comment: @RaG I.. don't think I can read that! Could you perhaps edit your question and put it there?

Answer (score 1):

The indirect part should be **`INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'"&"!E:E")`** for the apostrophe. It works